# Эмуляция Enum, но с доп. методами. Корректно ли?

Tags: php

В языке *C#* есть перечисления (enum). Удобная вещь, чтобы не заводить магические числа/строки/значения. Я решил сделать подобное на *PHP*. Сделал это в виде класса с константами. Например так:

```
class ColorEnum {
    const RED = 'red';
    const GREEN = 'green';
    const BLUE = 'blue';
}
```

Но проблема заключается в том, что для большинства этих классов перечислений я должен показывать пользователю их наименования на русском, например если это какой-нибудь dropdown в форме или карточке детальной информации об объекте (выбранный цвет: красный). Из-за этого в каждый класс перечисления мне приходится добавлять метод, который возвращает словарь, с ключом константы и значением-на русском:

```
class ColorEnum {
    const RED = 'red';
    const GREEN = 'green';
    const BLUE = 'blue';

    private static $colorsMap = [self::RED => 'Красный', self::GREEN => 'Зелёный', self::BLUE => 'Синий'];

    public static function getColorsMap():array {
        return self::$colorsMap;
    }
}
```

Как итог: я потерял "чистоту" и смысл перечислений (как мне кажется).

Вопрос: при текущих задачах правильно ли я сделал или нужно класс перечислений оставлять "чистым", а методы и словари ключ-значение для пользователя где-то как-то еще формировать? Где и как?

Comment: Лучше сделайте базовый абстрактный класс с методом getMap, который возвращает protected static $map, или рефлексией константы собрать, но тогда без локализации). Если SplEnum ещё не умер, можно на него посмотреть.

Comment: отделите мух от котлет, бизнес-логику с вашим перечслением от представления/хтмл и все проще станет. Если где-то надо показывать русское название, то это явно вообще не относится к самому классу перечисления. это задача представления. Используйте какой-нибудь механизм вывода сообщений,  `gettext` например прикрутите, и где надо выводите локализованные на нужный язык сообщения вида `site.colors.red` и т..п

Comment: @teran так дело не в локализации и нужном языке. Язык на ресурсе будет один - русский. И все данные, например из БД, будут вноситься/выводитьсяy на русском, все пункты меню, разделы и пр. чисто на русском и т.д. То есть эти перечисления не являются попыткой локализации, а именно попыткой работать с идентифицируемыми данными, а не магическими числами (например в условии `if` или `switch/case`). Программисту всё равно, а пользователю эти же данные в удобном виде нужно. Разве это задача локализации в текущей задаче?

Comment: то что язык один, не  значит что инструментарий локализации использовать нельзя. вы разгрузите классы от этой ерунды с переводами, код станет чище; соберете все переводы в одном месте, их будет проще редактировать; переводы не будут кешироваться вместе с кодом в opcache; сразу получите функционал с написаниями слов во множественном числе и многое другое; в перспективе будет легко добавить новый язык, если понадобится; добавление новых падежей не будет приводить к дублирования и расширению кода (вдруг вам вместо `один/два`понадобится выводить `первый/второй` и т.п.,)

Answer (score 0):

Самый красивый способ который мне известен

```
class ColorEnum
{
    const RED = 'red';
    const GREEN = 'green';
    const BLUE = 'blue';

    public static function getColor(): array
    {
        return [
            self::RED => 'Красный',
            self::GREEN => 'Зелёный',
            self::BLUE => 'Синий',
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: По факту, у меня сейчас так и есть. Только я сделал через массив специально, на случай если вдруг всё же прикручу еще методы для работы со списком или константами.